# Gekko: Fixed Parameter and fixed Variable value changes after solving

Tags: gekko

I am developing a mathematical process model based on the gekko package (version 1.0.2) to solve the balance equations (partial differential equations), and I observed a strange behavior when defining fixed parameter values for a dynamic simulation.

At a specific number of defined parameters or variables, the fixed values change after solving. Therefore, I assume that there must be something like a memory limit.
Furthermore, the maximum achievable number of correct fixed values depends if a name of the parameter or variable is set or, in the case of variables, if a lower or upper bound is defined.

**In general:** the number of correct values decreases with the number of information (name, value, lb, ub) given.

Please look at this minimal working example to reproduce the strange behavior:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
        

m = GEKKO(remote = False)
time = np.linspace(0,2,2+1)
m.time = time
a_value = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]


num = 685 # limit with m.Param()
a = [m.Param(value=a_value, name="a_"+str(i)) for i in range(num)]

b = [m.Var(value=0, lb=0, name="b_"+str(i)) for i in range(num)]

for i in range(num):
    m.Equation(b[i].dt() == a[i])

m.options.IMODE = 7
m.options.SOLVER = 1
# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp = False) 
m.cleanup()
        
for i in range(num):
    for t in range(len(m.time)):
        if(a[i].value[t] != a_value[t]):
            print("i=" + str(i) + ", t=" + str(t) + ": wrong value -> a.value[" + str(t) + "]: " + str(a[i].value[t]) + ", a_value[" + str(t) + "]: " + str(a_value[t]))
```

This code leads to the following output:

```
i=684, t=0: wrong value -> a.value[0]: 1.0, a_value[0]: 2.0
i=684, t=1: wrong value -> a.value[1]: 1.0, a_value[1]: 3.0
i=684, t=2: wrong value -> a.value[2]: 1.0, a_value[2]: 4.0
```

If m.Var() is used instead of m.Param(), the maximum number of correct values increases, but there is still a limit:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
        

m = GEKKO(remote = False)
time = np.linspace(0,2,2+1)
m.time = time
a_value = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

num = 1301 # limit with m.Var()
a = [m.Var(value=0, name="a_"+str(i)) for i in range(num)]
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(len(m.time)):
        m.fix(a[i], val=a_value[j], pos=j)

b = [m.Var(value=0, lb=0, name="b_"+str(i)) for i in range(num)]

for i in range(num):
    m.Equation(b[i].dt() == a[i])

m.options.IMODE = 7
m.options.SOLVER = 1
# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp = False) 
m.cleanup()
        
for i in range(num):
    for t in range(len(m.time)):
        if(a[i].value[t] != a_value[t]):
            print("i=" + str(i) + ", t=" + str(t) + ": wrong value -> a.value[" + str(t) + "]: " + str(a[i].value[t]) + ", a_value[" + str(t) + "]: " + str(a_value[t]))
```

Output:

```
i=1300, t=0: wrong value -> a.value[0]: 3.0, a_value[0]: 2.0
i=1300, t=2: wrong value -> a.value[2]: 3.0, a_value[2]: 4.0
```

Hence, my question is: **Can this maximum limit be increased by the user or is there a workaround?** (as I can not decrease the size of my problem)

Comment: Thanks for posting this example. It looks like a bug (limitation) in the code based on how FORTRAN reads each line of the data file when it is `IMODE=7`. It transforms the data file into a column-oriented form instead of a row-oriented form to deal with large number of time points. I'm currently working on it and will post a solution once the solution is ready. Once resolved, there should be no limit. A temporary work-around for your problem is to have Gekko write a row-oriented data file `gk0_model.csv` in `m._path`.

Comment: @john-hedengren Thank you very much for your answer! I tested your proposed workaround with a transposed `gk0_model.csv` file and it worked without any problems (I tested up to 5000 parameters and I noticed no limitation). I am really looking forward to the update of APMonitor with the bugfix. Just as an additional information: the bug exists for all (dynamic) `IMODE -> 4,5,6,7,8,9` and is not limited just to `IMODE=7`.

Comment: Thanks for that additional information. I added it as a new issue in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/142

Comment: Thank you for adding the issue in the GitHub repository.
For everyone who is interested: The workaround can be implemented by adjusting the second last line of the `_write_csv` function in `gk_write_files.py`:
`np.savetxt(os.path.join(self._path,file_name), np.vstack((hdr.split(","),csv_data[:,1:].T)).T,delimiter=",",comments='',fmt='%s'+',%1.25s'*len(csv_data[:,1:].T))`.
However, now the maximum number of timesteps could be affected by the bug.

Comment: Thanks for posting the temporary fix!